# PowerShell SSH only works on LAN but not over the internet

Tags: powershell, ssh, lan, wan

I have made a firewall exception and all should be working

working from a home internet DHCP

even tried turning off firewall on both domain and home to no avail.

here is my code (which is just the guide):

```
# Install the OpenSSH Client
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0

# Install the OpenSSH Server
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0

# Start the sshd service
Start-Service sshd

# OPTIONAL but recommended:
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'

# Confirm the firewall rule is configured. It should be created automatically by setup.
Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *ssh*

# There should be a firewall rule named "OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP", which should be enabled
# If the firewall does not exist, create one
New-NetFirewallRule -Name sshd -DisplayName 'OpenSSH Server (sshd)' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 22
```

here is the rundown of what I'm doing with the code.
[SSH client to client hosting in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68342666/ssh-client-to-client-hosting-in-powershell)

Comment: Your router will likely be blocking SSH port by default. You'll need to allow port 22 to forwarding rules in the router.

Comment: Any error messages or warnings?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open port 22/TCP for using SSH outside your LAN.

This can usually be achieved in your router configuration, or by contacting your provider. After doing this successfully you can use your WAN IP to access SSH outside your network.